# Haskell: How can we define a general purpose logging wrapper function?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, decorator

Suppose that we want to have a function `log` which accepts any function, wraps around the function and does logging for input/output of the function. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
func log(func f, input) {
  var output = f(input);
  log_data(input);
  log_data(output);
}
```

How is this possible in Haskell? How can we define a general function pointer with a general list of inputs in a function call? This could be something similar to Python decorators for loggin.

**To be more specific**, I want a general mechanism to add logging for input/output of all functions in my application. Of course this is possible by adding two lines of code for each function to log input and output but I want a general-purpose solution which works for all functions with any input.

A sample logging decorator in Python:

```
def logged(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Logging..."
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Call finished"
        return r
    return wrapped

@logged
def myfunc(myarg):
    print "my function", myarg
    return "return value"
```

Comment: What exactly should your logging do? In imperative languages logging is used for tracking the sequential execution and/or to store computation results based on some input. In imperative languages these two purposes are quite the same, but in Haskell not.

Comment: `\f x -> print x >> f x >>= \r -> print r >> return r`

Comment: Pure code? Monadic code? IO monad only? Lazy/strict semantics? There are a lot of options to think about. The code from @user2407038 is valid, but only works in the IO monad. A solution working in pure code with more lazy semantics would be something along Debug.Trace or [http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TraceUtils-0.1.0.2/docs/Debug-TraceUtils.html][TraceUtils]. Still, these are for debugging and tracing only, as these functions are not referentially transparent, so the output may be at very unexpected places.

Comment: @user2407038 does this code work even if f has multiple inputs? What does x represent?

Comment: This is far more complex in Haskell. E.g. `f n = [n..]`, what do you want to log here, precisely? For debugging reasons, I'd temporarily use `Debug.Trace`. For more serious stuff, you need to work in some logging monad, so that you don't break purity.

Comment: @mahdix If you want such a function to be poly-variadic, that is a different story. In general, such things are more trouble than they are worth. If you really must, just define `log1, log2, log3` etc for different arities. `x` is a parameter bound by a lambda in `\f x -> ...` - I suppose I should have called it `input`. @MichaelO Naturally, the pseudo-code is imperative so the corresponding real Haskell code will have to be inside IO (for there to be any hope of saying what "this" even is in Haskell)

Comment: @chi I want to log all the inputs and outputs of function 'X' when it is called.

Comment: Please post an example of Python decorators for logging.